# dataSnapshot Not Working "cannot resolve symbol dataSnapshot"

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing Firebase in my Android Project. But it seems that the function dataSnapshot is not being initialized. It is underlined in red.

Here is the Code for my .java

```
table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        if(dataSnapshot.child(edtphone.getText().toString()).exists()) {

            mDialog.dismiss();
            User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtphone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
            if (user.getPassword().equals(edtpass.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(signin.this, "Sign In Successful", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(signin.this, "Sign In Failed", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(signin.this, "User Not Found", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Both of my dataSnapshot functions are not working.
I have tried changing it to DataSnapshot but then the `.child` is not working

Is there an update for this function or a different syntax to try?

Changing to DataSnapshot returns this error

> Non-static method 'child(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onDataChange() has an argument called `snapshot` and **not** `dataSnapshot`, hence that error:

> "cannot resolve symbol dataSnapshot"

What you have to do is to change all occurrences of `dataSnapshot` with `snapshot`:

```
  table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                                                                //
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                       //
                    if(snapshot.child(edtphone.getText().toString()).exists()) {

                        mDialog.dismiss();
                                     //
                        User user = snapshot.child(edtphone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                        if (user.getPassword().equals(edtpass.getText().toString())) {
                            Toast.makeText(signin.this, "Sign In Successful", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(signin.this, "Sign In Failed", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(signin.this, "User Not Found", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

The following operation will also not work:

> Changing to DataSnapshot returns this error:
> Non-static method 'child(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Because the `child()` method is an **instance** method and **not** a static method.

Comment: Thank You So Much! Ill make sure to double check the code more carefully now!